# Generate consecutive IPv4 addresses based on a given integer

Tags: c#

```
/// <summary>
    /// Create IP part of the client information payload.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">Index of the current client being generated.</param>
    /// <returns>Simulated client IP address.</returns>
    private string CreateClientIp(UInt32 index)
    {
        index = (index << 2) + 3;
        return $"192.{(index >> 16) & 0xFF}.{(index >> 8) & 0xFF}.{index & 0xFF}";
    }
```

The following method is generating IP's starting from 192.0.0.3 with an increment of 3. I would like to have my first address 192.0.0.2(to avoid Network address as well as first one which usually is used for GW) and the next ones incremented by one. Any thoughts on this?
Thanks!

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23356801/how-can-i-increment-an-ip-address-by-a-specified-amount

Comment: I don't see in the code where the starting value is 192.0.0.3.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're meaning by simulate but be aware that only [192.168/16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) is available for private use (of addresses that start `192.`)

Comment: Be careful not to use an address ending in 255.  So starting at 2 and going to 254 is ok.  then you have to increment next subnet.

Comment: @gunr2171 When the above method is called with an index = 2 the following addresses are generated: 192.0.0.3 and 192.0.0.6.

Comment: @PaulU so if calling the method with `index = 2` creates 192.0.0.3, what do you think calling the method with `index = 1` will do?

Comment: Do you really want string? Since IPs are really integers, it seems like either returning `int` plus having a separate formatting function or returning the existing System.Net.IPAddress would be more appropriate.

Comment: @jdweng You can use 255 if you also use a less common subnet masks. /24 is the most common, but it's perfectly fine to use /23, /22, /21, etc all the way up to /16, if that's what you need, and then the 255 address are okay.

Comment: Do you really need it one by one? You could use  nested loops with checks and generate a list of string addresses to use as needed.

Comment: @gunr2171 no matter the index, my first IP is 192.0.0.3 and the next one is incremented with 3 an so on...above method is called as many times as index value is.

Comment: Addresses ending in 255 are reserved for Broadcast IP for the subnet.

Comment: @aamartin2k No, is not really necessary but I wanted to have them in order. This are some fake clients that are inserted in a DB for testing purposes only.

Comment: @jdweng That's just not always true.

Comment: @Joel Coehoom : Just to be safe don't you recommend not using the 255 address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest thing to do I think is to use the IPAddress and manipulate the bytes being used to create them. Use ToString() on the returned IP addresses if you need it in string form.

```
    static void Main(string[] _)
    {
        var address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.2");

        foreach (var ip in GetTestAddresses(address, 300))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ip);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetTestAddresses(IPAddress start, int count)
    {
        var bytes = start.GetAddressBytes();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            var part4 = bytes[^1];
            var part3 = bytes[^2];

            if (part4 < 255)
            {
                ++part4;
            }
            else if (part3 < 255)
            {
                part4 = 0;
                ++part3;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

            bytes[^1] = part4;
            bytes[^2] = part3;

            yield return new IPAddress(bytes);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best result would use a native C#/.Net IPv4 struct. Unfortunately, .Net doesn't have good native IPv4 tools, or at least I'm not aware of them. There is `System.Net.IPAddress`, but it tries to support both IPv6 and IPv4 in the same place. It forces us to store 64 bits plus a bunch of extra flags when a simple 32-bit value would do.

Failing that, we should be thinking in terms of `uint` values rather than strings, at least for the lower-level math stuff. I'm sure there's a NuGet library that would help, but this is simple enough I can put it in this answer.

I also think this is a good (or fun, at least) place to use some interesting linq techniques, such as iterators and custom operators. We can make an easy sequence that returns `uint` values from a given starting point and is aware of broadcast addresses:

```cs
public static uint MaskFromCidr(int cidr)
{
    //cidr is the number of 1's at the start of the result
    // So /24 is 11111111111111111111111100000000 is 255.255.255.0
    return uint.MaxValue << (32-cidr);
}

public static bool CheckMask(uint IP, uint mask)
{
    return (IP | mask) == uint.MaxValue;
}
    
public static bool CheckMask(uint IP, int cidr)
{
    return CheckMask(IP, MaskFromCidr(cidr));
}

public static IEnumerable<uint> IPSequence(uint start_address, int cidr = 24)
{
    uint mask = MaskFromCidr(cidr);
            
    while (!CheckMask(start_address, mask))
    {
        yield return start_address;
        start_address++;
    }
}
```

Then add a linq operator and a formatting function for good measure:

```cs
public static IEnumerable<T> EveryNth<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        if (i % n == 0)
        {
            yield return item;
            i = 0; //for LARGE sequences, prevent int overflow
        }
        i++;
    }
}

public static string DottedQuadFromUInt(uint IP)
{   
    return $"{(IP >> 24) & 0xFF}.{(IP >> 16) & 0xFF}.{(IP >> 8) & 0xFF}.{IP & 0xFF}";
}
```

And then tie it all together like this:

```cs
uint start = 3232235522; //192.168.0.2 https://www.vultr.com/resources/ipv4-converter/?ip_address=192.168.0.2
var addresses = IPSequence(start).EvernNth(3).Take(2).Select(DottedQuadFromUInt);
foreach(var address in addresses)
{
    Console.WriteLine(address);
}
```

Notice I used `192.168.0.2` instead of `192.0.0.2`. The latter is **public-routable**, and you *should not use it* for an internal address.

See it work here:

---

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ho2rqg

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is better code to avoid addresses ending in 255.:

```
       public class IncrementIP
        {
            byte[] array = new byte[4];
            public IncrementIP(string IP)
            {
                array = IP.Split(new char[] { '.' }).Select(x => byte.Parse(x)).ToArray();
            }
            public string Increment()
            {
                int lsb = array[3] + 3;
                if (lsb <= 254)
                {
                    array[3] = (byte)lsb;
                }
                else
                {
                    array[3] = 2;
                    for (int i = 2; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        if (array[i] == 254)
                        {
                            array[i] = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            array[i] += 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return string.Join(".", array);
            }
        }
```